# KendoUI Grid client paging alway show zero on total page

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create kendo paging grid and load all data from server, then show on grid using trasport configuration. But it always show page zero number on grid. And show wording on footer "no items to display". 
This is my coding:

```
<div id="grid"></div>

    $(function(){

        var data_scheme = {
            data: "expert",
            model: {
                id: "expertId",
                fields: {
                    expertId: { type: 'string',nullable: true },
                    name: { type: 'string', nullable: false, editable: true,
                        validation: { required: true, validationMessage: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
                    },
                    address: { type: 'string', nullable: false, editable: true },
                    email: { type: 'string', nullable: false, editable: true,
                        validation: { required: false, email: true, validationMessage:'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  }
                    },
                    phone: { type: 'string', nullable: false, editable: true }
                }
            },
            errors: "errors"
        };

        var dataSourceE = {
            transport: {
                read: { url: '<?php echo site_url('expert/listing'); ?>', contentType: 'application/json' }
            },
            error: function(e) { alert(e.errors); },
            schema: data_scheme,
            batch: false,
            pageSize: 2,
            serverPaging: false,
            total: "total"
        };



        var th_attribute = { 'class': 'table-header-cell', style: 'font-weight:bold;text-align: center' };
        var td_attribute = { 'class': 'table-cell', style: 'text-align: center'};
        var tdleft_attribute = { 'class': 'table-cell', style: 'text-align: left'};
        $('#grid').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSourceE,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            editable: 'inline',
            selectable: 'row',
            resizable: true,
            sortable: true,
            serverAggregates:true,
            pageable: {
                input: true,
                numeric: false,
                refresh: true
            },
            columns: [
                {field: 'name', title: 'Name', headerAttributes: th_attribute, attributes: tdleft_attribute},
                {field: 'expertId', hidden:true, title: 'ExpertId', headerAttributes: th_attribute, attributes: tdleft_attribute},
                {field: 'address', title: 'Address', width: 200, headerAttributes: th_attribute, attributes: tdleft_attribute},
                {field: 'email', title: 'Email', width: 180, headerAttributes: th_attribute, attributes: tdleft_attribute,
                    template: '<a href="mailto:#=email#">#=email#</a>'},
                {field: 'phone', title: 'Phone', width: 180,headerAttributes: th_attribute, attributes: tdleft_attribute},
                {command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: 180, headerAttributes: th_attribute}
            ]
        });

    });
```

And this is json from calling localhost/expert/index page:

```
    {"expert":[
{"expertId":"1","name":"aaaaaaa","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"sman@hotmail.com"},
{"expertId":"2","name":"bbbbbbb","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"ganjana@hotmail.com"},
{"expertId":"3","name":"ccccccc","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"ganjana2@hotmail.com"},
{"expertId":"4","name":"ddddddd","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"asdf@asdf.comss"},
{"expertId":"5","name":"eeeeeee","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"dddddddd@asdf.com"},
{"expertId":"6","name":"fffffff","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"asdfasdff@ad.com"},
{"expertId":"7","name":"ggggggg","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"adfadf@www.comaS"},
{"expertId":"8","name":"hhhhhhh","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"sfdhdhj@ass.com"},
{"expertId":"9","name":"kkkkkkk","address":"ssssssssss","phone":"8082201270","email":"asdf@eed.com"}
], "total":9}
```

I try to search solution on google and change code follow these solution, but not work yet.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try putting `total:"total"` after `errors:"errors"` in data_scheme like this :

```
errors:"errors",
total:"total"
```

basically, `total` is a property on `schema` object. (that's how it works for me :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can fix this bug follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732312/kendo-grid-footer-not-initializing-on-page-load).
By move total from datasourceE to schema.